# Java send parameterized generic type as valueType

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that returns a type that it is given:

```
T foo(Class<T> valueType) {...};

String s = foo(Java.lang.String.class);
```

I'm trying to send a generic type as my class, but getting compiler errors. For example, let's say I want to return an ArrayList of Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> list = foot(ArrayList<String>.class)
```

the parameter "String" is giving errors.  Is there anyway I can specify the generic type to return?

Answer (score 1):

The runtime `class` field value does not depend on the generic type you apply, and this syntax is illegal. More on this [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ401).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you(edited)?

```
ArrayList list = foot(ArrayList.class)
```

Comment: probably `ArrayList list = foot(ArrayList.class)`?

Comment: This compiles, but I want to return a parameterized object.

Comment: Then using a wrapper might be a good idea. pass the parameterized object to a wrapper and then pass the wrapped class to your actual method. would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the input or output of the method:

```
ArrayList<String> list = foot((Class<ArrayList<String>>)(Class<?>)ArrayList.class);
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)foot(ArrayList.class);
```

Basically, the `Class` class does not work well with generics, because it represents a runtime thing, whereas generics works at compile time. At runtime, there is just one class object for `ArrayList` in the program. Even if you call it `Class<ArrayList<String>>` or `Class<ArrayList<Integer>>` or `Class<ArrayList>`, it's still the same single object. So what type should it be? There's no simple answer that works for everything.

The Java language decided that the class literal `ArrayList.class` should just have the type `Class<ArrayList>`. But that causes problems when you want an expression of type `Class<ArrayList<String>>`, so you have to bend the types.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are here only concerned about static types, this trick might be useful:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T>
Class<T> appropriateClass(T... args) {
    return (Class<T>) args.getClass().getComponentType();
}

Class<ArrayList<String>> c = appropriateClass();
ArrayList<String> list = foo(c);
```

Actually I am not very proud of the trick. But you might want to give it a try.

If you test it:

```
System.out.println(c); // prints "class java.util.ArrayList"
```

So it is equivalent to an ugly cast like `(Class<ArrayList<String>>) (Class<?>) ArrayList.class`.

If you actually need to have different tokens for `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList` at runtime, you should use the `TypeToken` technique as mentioned by Sean Patrick Floyd.

Answer (score 0):

Type Erasure rears its ugly head. Essentially, Java does compile-time checking on the generic `<…>` clauses, then *erases* them from the run-time objects, losing the information forever. Nasty, eh? Since `.class` metaobjects are referenced at run-time, they suffer from the erasure as well.

`ArrayList<String>.class` is Erased at compile-time, to be `ArrayList.class`.

If you want type-safety with the generics, you'll have to pass in two parameters, e.g.

`ArrayList<String> foo = foot(ArrayList.class, String.class)`